# What's the latency of the ALB Listener priority evaluation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-alb

The way I have my app set up is:

1 Application LoadBalancer with 2 listeners HTTP and HTTPS.

For both of those listeners, I have, for each, a [Listener Rule](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-listenerrule.html) set up that points to a target group.

Each target group is its own application and has its own domain, which I use as a [Rule condition](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/APIReference/API_RuleCondition.html) in the Listener (host header) for forwarding.

The question I have is, since Listener Rules must have a unique [priority](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-update-rules.html#update-rule-priority)

Would there be any noticable latency in server responses, given that I had 100 Listener Rules that pointed to different target group that have different domains?

I'm worried about, say, the 100th Listener Rule causing slow performance for the Target Group it's forwarding traffic to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from AWS support:

> Hi, Thank you for reaching out to AWS Support. My name is Kriti and I
>   will be assisting you with your case today.
>
> As I understand, you have an ELB with both HTTP and HTTPS listeners.
>   You want to confirm whether or not different multiple listener rules
>   will create any significant latency because of their priorities.
>
> I can see that you have 2 listeners with 2 custom listener rules for
>   each of your listeners in the ALB:
>   DevBaseALB1-xxxxxxxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com I tried to replicate
>   your concern by setting up multiple listener rules pointing to
>   different target groups in an Application Load Balancer. All the rules
>   had different priorities as you rightly mentioned. From my findings, I
>   could confirm that any differences in latency observed for different
>   listener rules with different priorities is negligible (in
>   milliseconds) and should have no significant impact on your
>   applications.  Please note that limit for rules per load balancer (not
>   counting default rules) is 100 [1]
>
> I hope this information was helpful and I was able to resolve your
>   query. Please feel free to reach out to us again in case you face any
>   further issues. We will be happy to help.
>
> Links:
>   1. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-limits.html
>
> Best regards,
>
> Kriti B. Amazon Web Services